# Why does Physics2D produce different results for AddForce() versus velocity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Why does **Gravity** in Physics2D engine for Unity2D act different when these two following lines of codes are implemented alternately?

For example, I have attached to my player sprite a Player Controller C# script:

```
private float speed = 500f;
RigidBody2D playerChar = null;
```

And  then to make my character **walk**:

```
Vector2 vec = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0);
playerChar.AddForce(vec * speed);
```

And the Gravity is set to 50

**Result 1:**  My character avatar falls down normally.

Meanwhile when I do:

```
Vector2 vec = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0);
playerChar.velocity  = (vec * speed);
```

And the Gravity is still set to 50

**Result 2:**  My character now takes a long time to fall (it slowly "floats" down).

Why is that?

Comment: I'm not a unity developer but my guess would be because adding force increases your acceleration, while adding velocity does not.  When you say your character floats...does it float slower at the beginning and slowly increase in how fast it floats?

Comment: it floats at a slow constant speed.  When I do AddForce() it accelerates downard.

Answer (score 3):

## This is because you're forcing the y component of the rigidbody's velocity to zero.

When you add force, it *adds*, it doesn't replace.

When you set the velocity, you're specifically setting it to a Vector2 that has a y value of 0, gravity then kicks in on the fixed update cycle and adds a small amount of gravity, causing your player to fall slowly. Then Update happens again and you force the y value back to 0 once more.